# Debian 12 Use Yubikey OR Password for sudo authentication

Tags: pam, yubikey

Using Debian12

Hi I want to know if I can use Yubikey OR Password  for sudo authentication.

So basically if I do `sudo date` I want to immediately get a prompt for the password but at the same time be able to hit my Yubikey and whatever I do first wins.

This is my current `/etc/pam.d/sudo` config:

```
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

# Passwordless auth with Yubico Yubikey
auth sufficient pam_u2f.so

# Standard Un*x authentication.
auth sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

With this config I first can use the yubikey but before I am able to enter the password I have to wait for the Yubikey to run into the timeout.

I want basically "Enter either your password or hit the Yubikey button"